# Let Authenticated User view the profile of other users in Laravel 4 using Sentry 2

Tags: php, laravel-4, userid, cartalyst-sentry

I'm sort of a newb to `Laravel 4` and `Sentry 2`, but i've managed to survive so far. I'm running into a problem right now, cause when im logged in as `userid(1)` and i want to view the profile of `userid(2)` i'm just seeing the information of userid(1) on the profile of userid(2).

I'm aware that using filters might come in handy at this, but if i have to be honest. I have no idea what i should look at etc.

I know this site is not meant for giving answers. But if someone could give me a bit of an answer, where to look, what i should keep in mind etc. that would be very much appreciated.

---EDIT---

Route:

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'), function(){

    Route::get('logout', 'HomeController@logout');
    Route::get('profile/{username}', 'ProfileController@getIndex');

});

Route::filter('auth', function($route)
{
    $id = $route->getParameter('id');
    if(Sentry::check() && Sentry::getUser()->id === $id) {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
});
```

ProfileController

```
public function getIndex($profile_uname)
    {
        if(Sentry::getUser()->username === $profile_uname) {
            // This is your profile
            return View::make('user.profile.index');
        } else {
            // This isn't your profile but you may see it!
            return ??
        }
    }
```

View

```
@extends('layouts.userprofile')

@section('title')
    {{$user->username}}'s Profile
@stop

@section('notification')
@stop

@section('menu')
    @include('layouts.menus.homemenu')
@stop

@section('sidebar')
    @include('layouts.menus.profilemenu')
@stop

@section('content')
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-lg-10">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h3>{{ $user->username }}</h3></div>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop

@section('footer')
@stop
```

Comment: Please show us some code: at least a controller a view related to your problem.

Comment: Will edit my original question in a second!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
<?php

public function getIndex($profile_uname)
{
    if(Sentry::getUser()->username === $profile_uname) {
        // This is your profile
        return View::make('user.profile.index');
    } else {
        // This isn't your profile but you may see it!
        return View::make('user.profile.index')->with('user', Sentry::findUserByLogin($profile_uname));
    }
}
```

If username is not your login column, then you can do it in two steps:

```
$userId = \Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User::where('username', $profile_uname)->first()->id;

return View::make('user.profile.index')->with('user', Sentry::findUserById($userId));
```

If you have a User model tied to your users table, you can just do:

```
$userId = User::where('username', $profile_uname)->first()->id;

return View::make('user.profile.index')->with('user', Sentry::findUserById($userId));
```

And in this last case you probably will be able to use that same model, since they would be the same in Sentry and pure Eloquent:

```
$user = User::where('username', $profile_uname)->first();

return View::make('user.profile.index')->with('user', $user);
```

Also, to avoid a conflict between your views related to the current logged user, you should rename the `$user` variable you are instantiating via `View::share()` or `View::composer()` from `$user` to `$loggedUser` or something like that.

Comment: Ofcourse.. so logical.. But...... I'm getting an error: A user could not be found with a login value of [username]. 

i've added a new field to the Sentry users table, this fields name = username. So i don't think this is the login value right?

Comment: I guess i should edit the sentry config file now to change the login value to username?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about this and edited to provide some more options. But, yes, you can edit sentry conf and set a new column to be used as login field.

Comment: Looking at your message, looks like your $profile_uname has a value of 'username' and not 'Jeroen'.

Comment: Ok it's working, but now another problem pops up. When i go to /profile/john I'm immediately getting logged in as that user. I can view it's profile but i'm also getting logged in as that user. 

I'm not fishing for getting straight answers, just trying to understand laravel and sentry a bit more.

Comment: That's correct @antonio But i manually edited it, so it's more 'universal' to understand

Comment: You mean, in your sidebar?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49258/discussion-between-jeroen-and-antonio-carlos-ribeiro)